# Symfony2 not firing kernel.terminate event

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

I'm going to upgrade my Symfony from 2.0 to 2.5 with all this guides:

```
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.3.md
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.4.md
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.5.md
```

My front page works but web debug toolbar throws "404 Not found".
After whole day searching and digging trought symfony code i found:

1. Web Debug Toolbar and Profiler looks fine but...
2. app/cache/dev/profiler is empty (whole cache has 0777 access)
3. kernel.terminate event wont fires (last noticed event is kernel.finish_request)
4. i can't find place where Kernel `terminate` method is called (that is the last place where i stuck)

Maybe someone has simmilar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
3) kernel.terminate event wont fires
```

Ensure all the services which are listening to 'kernal.terminate' event are correctly configured. i.e Symfony should be able to instantiate the services which are listening to 'kernal.terminate' event.

Reason:
As Symfony dispatches 'kernal.terminate' event, the dispatcher first gets the list of services that are listening to this event. If it fails to get the list of services, it throws an exception. Since this exception is happening on terminate and the response is already sent, you will not be able to see the exception anywhere, other than logs.

If it fails to get the list of services that are listing to the 'kernal.terminate', it is most possible that there is an error in instantiating any of the services due to any reason. Eg. the arguments passed to constructor are wrong/not available.

Tip: Keep tailing symfony logs and php logs while debugging.

```
4) i can't find place where Kernel terminate method is called
```

You can find it in `app_dev.php` or `app.php`

Comment: Last line of your answer points me to the right direction. When you look at [github 2.0 tag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.0/web/app_dev.php) and compare it with [2.5 tag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.5/web/app_dev.php) you can see there is no $kernel->terminate() line. Thanks!